# Convert multiple rows into a single row with multiple columns using LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let's consider following two tables:

**Guest**

```
GuestID    FirstName    Email     
----------------------------------------------
3          Sam          sam.billings@gmail.com
```

and

**GuestAddress**

```
AddressID    GuestID    AddressType    IsPrimaryAddress   Address1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
3            3          1              True               ABC
4            3          2              False              XYZ
```

I expect output something like this:

```
GuestID    FirstName   Email         IsPrimaryAddress  Address1  IsPrimaryAddress Address1
3          Sam         sam.billings@gmail.com  True    ABC       False             XYZ
```

I found this type of solution for SQL Server, but I can not convert it to a linq query. I tried linq query but it returns two rows. Is this possible with a linq query?

Comment: you can't have 2 `IsPrimaryAddress` properties in the same object

Comment: I want result in a single row, no matter IsPrimaryAddress property name changed or not. I mean, no problem if we need to rename as IsPrimaryAddress1 and IsPrimaryAddress2 as an output. @adiga

Comment: Normally this type of result is represented in EF as `Guest` object having collection of `GuestAddress` objects. Which should be your entity model anyway.

Comment: Can you talk us through **why** you want this?

Comment: I need for my excel export sheet where i am creating a dummy gridview and  export it as a excel file. But my requirement excel output with an single row for each GuestId. @mjwills

Answer (score 1):

You can try [GroupJoin](https://www.dotnetperls.com/groupjoin) extension method and generate the result below.

```
var result = db.Guests.GroupJoin(db.GuestAddresses,
                            guest => guest.GuestID,
                            address => address.GuestID,
                            (g, groupedAddress) => new
                            {
                                GuestID = g.GuestID,
                                FirstName = g.FirstName,
                                Email = g.Email,
                                IsPrimaryAddress = groupedAddress.Any(x => x.AddressType == 1) ? groupedAddress.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsPrimaryAddress).IsPrimaryAddress : false,
                                PrimaryAddress = groupedAddress.Any(x => x.AddressType == 1) ? groupedAddress.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsPrimaryAddress).Address: string.Empty,
                                IsSecondayAddress = groupedAddress.Any(x => x.AddressType == 2) ? groupedAddress.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsPrimaryAddress).IsPrimaryAddress : false,
                                SecondayAddress = groupedAddress.Any(x => x.AddressType == 2) ? groupedAddress.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsPrimaryAddress).Address : string.Empty,
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: there is an error in guests and guestAddress at very beginning of the query I guess it could be db.Guests and db.GuestAddresses, isn't it? @SMA

Comment: Yes it should be db.Guests and db.GuestAddress. I have updated the answer.

Comment: but still error in 'x => x.IsPrimaryAddress' . the error message says: cannot implicitly convert type bool to bool... @SMA

Comment: Can you change "groupedAddress.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsPrimaryAddress).IsPrimaryAddress" to "groupedAddress.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == 1).IsPrimaryAddress" and "groupedAddress.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsPrimaryAddress).IsPrimaryAddress" to "groupedAddress.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == 2).IsPrimaryAddress"?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED with multiple guest and multiple address** I have checked, try this:

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Guest guest1 = new Guest { Email = "tom@gmail.com", FirstName = "tom", GuestID = 1 };
        Guest guest2 = new Guest { Email = "jerry@gmail.com", FirstName = "jerry", GuestID = 2 };
        List<Guest> listGuests = new List<Guest>();
        listGuests.Add(guest1);
        listGuests.Add(guest2);

        List<Address> AddressList = new List<Address>();
        Address address1 = new Address { AddressID = 1, AddressType = "1", GuestID = 1, IsPrimaryAddress = false, Address1 = "address1" };
        Address address2 = new Address { AddressID = 2, AddressType = "2", GuestID = 1, IsPrimaryAddress = true, Address1 = "address2" };
        Address address3 = new Address { AddressID = 1, AddressType = "1", GuestID = 2, IsPrimaryAddress = true, Address1 = "address3" };
        Address address4 = new Address { AddressID = 1, AddressType = "1", GuestID = 2, IsPrimaryAddress = false, Address1 = "address4" };

        AddressList.Add(address1);
        AddressList.Add(address2);
        AddressList.Add(address3);
        AddressList.Add(address4);

        var queryResult = from primaryAddress in ( AddressList.Where(x => x.IsPrimaryAddress == true))
                          join secAddress in (AddressList.Where(x => x.IsPrimaryAddress == false))
                          on primaryAddress.GuestID equals secAddress.GuestID
                          join guest in listGuests on  secAddress.GuestID equals guest.GuestID
                          select new GuestAddress
                            {
                                FirstName = guest.FirstName,
                                Email = guest.Email,
                                GuestID = primaryAddress.GuestID,
                                IsPrimaryAddress = primaryAddress.IsPrimaryAddress,
                                Address1 = primaryAddress.Address1,
                                SecondayAddress = secAddress.Address1,
                                IsSecondayAddress = secAddress.IsPrimaryAddress
                            };

    }
}
public class Guest
{
    public int GuestID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public int GuestID { get; set; }
    public string AddressType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
}
public class GuestAddress
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int GuestID { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsSecondayAddress { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string SecondayAddress { get; set; }

}
```

}